# MariaDB Galera Cluster Replication problems

Tags: replication, mariadb, galera

I set up a galera cluster with 2 nodes and an arbitrator.

The cluster starts up correctly, firewall rules exist to pass traffic on all ports needed for the replication (including rsync) and a new member successfully joins the cluster (no errors, state changes from join to sync).

Adding a new database on host A, database shows up on host B.

Deleting the database on host B, database deleted on host A.

Changing an existing database (changing a field in a table) on either host, doesn't work. The change does not get replicated to the other host. No errors are shown in any of the logs.

Tried resetting the quorum and then adding the second member again, doesn't need to reset since the primary host knows that the quorum is ok.

Rebootstrapping the cluster doesn't work either.

I'm at a loss. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that old databases (created before the cluster was created) were MyISAM.

For the replication to work, the databases need to be converted to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

MyISAM tables updates can be replicated by enabling [wsrep_replicate_myisam](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/galera-cluster-system-variables/#wsrep_replicate_myisam). But, given MyISAM is a non-transactional engine, this feature is considered experimental.